# Creating a tar archive from files stored in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, tar

I would like create a tar archive from multiple files in GCS and store the resulting tar in GCS as well. It doesn't look like `gsutil` or the python google cloud storage api provide the ability to do this - is my only option to download the files, tar them, and then upload the tar to GCS? The fileset has the potential to be quite large so ideally I would like to accomplish this without downloading all the source files.

Comment: My belief is that yes ... you have to retrieve the data from GCS and then tar them all together and upload the result.  You may be able to do this with streaming so that the data doesn't ALL need to reside on the compute at one time.  Can you explain why you'd want to tar up all the files into one single object?

Comment: I'd like to create a pytorch [webdataset](https://github.com/webdataset/webdataset) which takes a tar archive as input.

Comment: You don't have other alternative to download all and tar them locally before uploading the tar to GCS.